# Text gets cropped on Safari Mobile when using column-count and column-gap (CSS3)

Tags: css, mobile-safari, multiple-columns, column-width

Here the code I'm using:

```
<ul>
<li>TEXT<br>TEXT</li>
<li>TEXT<br>TEXT</li>
<li>TEXT<br>TEXT</li>
</ul>


ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 90px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 90px;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 90px;
}
```

The problem is that with Safari Mobile the text after the `<br>` gets cropped (no problem with other browsers.. well, for IE < 10 I use a dirty hack but I don't care about it). Here's the page where you can reproduce the issue:
http://goo.gl/ojWx9

And this is a screenshot from Safari Mobile:
[image: Screenshot from Safari iOS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large column gap coupled with "white-space: nowrap" is causing the content to extend beyond the column. This causes the clipping bug in Mobile Safari.

You need to either reduce the column gap size to fit the text or allow linebreaks to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know how I missed that white-space:nowrap! It's strange though to see how differently Safari Mobile renders the list. In desktop browsers even if I zoom to the same resolution of the iPhone, li are displayed on one line. On Safari Mobile instead it's like this (that still fixes the issue, it's just for curiosity that I note this): http://db.tt/OQscaeqO

Comment: Oh, and I have in style.css -webkit-text-size-adjust:100% on #main :)

Comment: Fixed that too. I set -webkit-text-size-adjust:100% on body instead that on #main. :)